# It is safe to use stdlib allocator functions with XLib allocations (those requiring `XFree`)

Tags: c, xlib

Just wondering whether it's okay to use standard allocator functions (in this case `realloc`) in a portable XLib application? From what I can see the XLib source just defines `XFree` to `free` but I'm not taking that as an assurance of portability, considering alternate or older impls.

My specific case atm. is just a cleaner way to use `XGet`/`XSetWMProtocols`, as I can just `realloc` the returned `Atom` array rather than needing to copy over. It's a small thing but  it'd be nice if I could.

If it's something that has "always been fine in practice" and as such assumedly always will be I don't really mind, I'm more focused here on correctness.

Thanks!

Comment: The `XFree`  doc says _"A NULL pointer cannot be passed to this function"_. For `free` passing `NULL` is safe. That leads me to think that there may be some differences in some cases. Perhaps platform dependend differences.

Comment: @TedLyngmo That's probably there in case `XFree()` is ever changed to do something more than just `free()`. Or maybe because the documentation was written before `free()` was allowed to accept `NULL` and never updated.

Comment: But in general you shouldn't make assumptions about how functions like these work. The wrappers exist for a reason.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that could very well be it. Some libraries have the possibility to supply custom allocators but I couldn't find that in XLib.

Comment: I think it's pretty ambitious to use Xlib (directly) at all.  It's pretty difficult, and these days, X clients written in C should probably use [XCB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCB) instead.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I need glX and didn't particularly want to deal with bridge code. (Also XCB is too modern for project requirements anyway ;/). I do agree though XCB is a much better time than XLib

Comment: @Barmar yeah I assumed it was *probably* not intended to be "cross contaminated" so to speak, but it's always worth an ask in case someone knows if a spec somewhere notes it down ;p